# Saving a Javascript object to a file

Tags: javascript, file, object, save

I need to save a Javascript object to a file, so it can be easily reloaded into a variable, modified and eventually re-saved. Is this feasible in Javascript and if so what's the best way to approach it. For example if I have:

```
o = {"test": 2};
```

How can I save it to a file, load, modify and save it? Exactly like `pickle` in Python.

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible with just javascript. The best you could do is use localStorage but that's not permanent storage

Comment: You need to serialize the object and send the result string to a script language (like Java, PHP, etc.) that is able to create a file out of this.

Comment: Why you want to fire the water ...? Impossible to re-save

Comment: Perhaps you want the new [FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)? Although I wouldn't put that in the bracket of *feasible*

Answer (score 4):

Despite all the answers to the contrary, this is indeed possible. However it is limited by browser support. You can use the new [FileSystem APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) in the latest versions of Chrome, etc:

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 1024, function(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('mystorage.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(file) {
        file.createWriter(function(writer) {
            var blob = new Blob(["putdatahere"], {type: 'text/plain'});
            writer.write(blob);
        });
    });
}, function() {
    console.log("Could not access file system");
});
```

Since you only want the files for your own uses, this sandboxed approach will work. There are a few more hoops you need to jump through (requesting a quota, creating a `Blob` object) but those are covered by the linked article and will all depend on your requirements.

Comment: Worth highlighting from the link you posted: "In April 2014, it was announced on public-webapps that the Filesystem API spec is not being considered by other browsers. For now, the API is Chrome-specific and it's unlikely to be implemented by other browsers and is no longer being standardized with the W3C."

Answer (score 3):

If you literally mean a file this is not possible client-side. However, if it's just the data you want to store and recall you can use a cookie if it's small.
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-deal-with-cookies-in-javascript/

If it's larger you have to use HTML5 LocalStorage. However, this will only work on newer browsers.

You could do this to make a visit counter:

```
//try to load the data
var o = localStorage.getItem("mydata");
//if the data is empty set the data
if(!o) o = {"test": 0};
//increment the test value inside of o by one each time
o.test++;
//save the data to local storage
localStorage.setItem("mydata", JSON.stringify(o));
```

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Again, this will ONLY work on modern browsers like Chrome.

The traditional method would be to send it via AJAX to a server side script written in PHP, Python, Ruby, Java, etc...

Comment: FYI your example doesn't work as written.  You have to first JSON.Stringify(o) in order to store it since localStorage is string-values only.

Answer (score 2):

You can save a file using the "download" attribute on a  element.
This is how it is done programmaticaly:

```
function saveJSON() {
   let data = "Whatever it is you want to save";
   let bl = new Blob([data], {
      type: "text/html"
   });
   let a = document.createElement("a");
   a.href = URL.createObjectURL(bl);
   a.download = "data.json";
   a.hidden = true;
   document.body.appendChild(a);
   a.innerHTML =
      "someinnerhtml";
   a.click();
}
```